# Code suggestion needed on this revision

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

I'm posting question to this site because simply my teacher, whom I can ask about this, is not available for days or so and I don't have anyone around to get help from.

Question : Finish the coding that would result in this numbers

2 3 5 (typed number on command prompt)
2 + 5 + 8 + 11 + 14 == 40

or

22 -2 7 (typed number on command prompt)
22 + 20 + 18 + 16 +14 + 12 + 10 == 112

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
    {
    int a, d, n;
    int i, s;
    scanf("_____", __, __, __);
    ___;
    for (i = 1; _____; i = i + 1) {
        _________________;
        printf("____ ", _________);
        _________________
        _________________
        _________________
        _________________
    }
    printf("%d\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Below is my answer

---------------My answer --------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
    {
    int a, d, n;
    int i, s;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &d, &n);
    s = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
       if (i != n)
           printf("%d + ", a + (i - 1)*d);
       if (i == n)
           printf("%d", a + (i - 1)*d);
       s = (a + a + (i - 1)*d)*i / 2;
    }
    printf(" == %d\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

When I submitted my answer to the teacher, he said that the error was "source code format not identical to each other." I couldn't ask further because he was busy and he had to leave for something important. I was wondering what was problem with my answer. Maybe because last print statement includes "== %d\n" instead of "%d\n"? and my statements inside "for" statement total up to 5 which are supposed to be six, as suggested on the question? My codes illustrated right numbers and results but I guess he wants some different coding...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is probably going to be one of those things only your teacher can answer.

Comment: The only thing that jumps out is `_________________;` (note the semi-colon) prior to the `printf` statement. This is a *guess*, but if his response was the format was not identical, the express `';'` at the end of the line suggests that the statement before the `printf'` is not a conditional. That said, I agree with the comment above, not knowing more about what your teacher expects, it is impossible to give you a concrete answer.

Comment: I think you need to literally "fill in the blanks" here.  So no "if" statements for instance.  And the non-blank items need to be preserved identically.  You didn't follow the required format, so you didn't get credit.  I assume the body of the "for" loop was meant to contain an assignment, a printf, and then four more assignments.

Comment: http://ideone.com/z8NBSv

Answer (score 1):

This is stupid. The idea of this is to solve the problem but not to match the formatting. The formatting is anyway is very stupid and the code itself is forcing one to write it badly. The design is too complicated for a simple problem which can solved like this below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int start, interval, numbers;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &start, &interval, &numbers);
    int sum = start;
    int finalSum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= numbers; i++, sum = sum + interval)
        finalSum += sum;
    printf("finalSum = %d\n", finalSum);

    return 0;
}
```

**In short this is a weird question and only your weird professor can answer it and may be you can put some sense into him/her**

**Sorry if I have been disrespectful to you or your professor but I had to say this**

Comment: You're not being disrespectful at all. I agree wholeheartedly: this teacher is setting a very bad example, both in the teaching method and with the poor quality code. The variable names are terrible! `a`, `d`, `n`, `i`, and `s`? Seriously? `i` and `n` can be forgiven, since they are customary names for an **i**ndex and a **n**umber of items. But `a`, `d`, and `s` are just ridiculous and would fail any professional code review. OP would be well advised to drop this class and use just about any online programming class, along with asking for advice from random strangers on the Internet.